# How to setup multiple Google Analtyics goals that have the same final page but different steps to get there

Tags: google-analytics, goals

I have a set of white papers that each have its own page on my site. Visitors have to fill out a basic form to get one. If they fill out the form, they get that specific paper. The "thank you" page is the same for all seven white papers I am offering, but the steps a user takes are different in that the white paper has its own page where the form lives.

[This](http://www.datalight.com/resources/bootstrapping-linux-from-nand-flash) is an example.

The resulting page is the same if they fill out that form, or if they fill the same form on a different page.

I currently have a different goal for each paper.  Since there are only seven papers it's OK.

Just want to make sure this is setup the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set all the page flow and finally the destination page in Google Analytic Goals, So in your case the destination page is same but it comes from different pages so you can create your own custom goal for each types.

```
Just Login to GA -> Admin Tab -> All Website Data -> Goals -> Custom -> Destination (type some name for your goal)
```

Then set the Destination page as regular and Click to enable the Funnel Option and set the full flow pages from 1 to before the destination page.

for eg:

```
  www.domain.com/page-1
  www.domain.com/page-2  
  www.domain.com/page-3 
  and finally www.domain.com/thanks.html
```

Another Goal flow is:

```
  www.domain.com/page-1
  www.domain.com/page-a  
  www.domain.com/page-b 
  and finally www.domain.com/thanks.html
```

set the Funnel Option properly in two cases before the last step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, no able to get to the page you are referencing: I go to admin, then under Profle is a Goals option.  I click that, and it lists my current goals. I can click Create a Goal.  I don't have a "custom" option at any point.

I can create a Destination goal, then add all the pages, page-1, page-2, page-3 to the funnel, but isn't that saying that the user will hit each one on the way to the destination?

Comment: did you check the url flow after setup the goal? , I used this technique and its work fine for me, Iam not sure why the custom option not available for you

Comment: Basically I can set a destination goal, and put in as many steps as I want.  I set it up, and I am running a test.  I will see the data later today or tomorrow to test it out